# docker-compose up leads to "client and server don't have same version (client : 1.14, server: 1.12)" error but client and server have the same version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

`docker version` prints:

```
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 990021a
```

`docker-compose --version` prints:

```
docker-compose 1.2.0
```

I installed docker with `apt-get install docker.io` and docker-compose with

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.2.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Answer (score 52):

Checkout the environment variable [COMPOSE_API_VERSION](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#/composeapiversion).

I was getting `ERROR: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.19, server: 1.18)`, then I did `export COMPOSE_API_VERSION=1.18` and problem sovled!

Comment: Thanks, saved a lot of my time

Answer (score 16):

This is an issue of docker API version used by docker-compose being higher than that that of docker daemon listening to serve.

Easiest way to fix is this to use an older version of docker-compose.

Here is my example but with different version mismatch:

```
$ docker-compose up

client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.17)
```

To fix it, I had to install a lower version of docker-compose(1.2 version instead of latest 1.3 version) using following command

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.2.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose``

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`
```

You can find different version of docker-compose at
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Based on your server version, you need to try different lower versioned docker-compose until one works.

Answer (score 15):

I think you just need to use a newer version of Docker. Presumably client version 1.14 is used internally in Compose.

Uninstall the apt-get version and follow the instructions on the Docker website to install Docker:

```
 wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Comment: I did that and when I try to use it I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you remove the previous version? You may just need to log in and out or something. Anyway, that script should have installed the lxc-docker package.

Comment: It does install it but I can't use it. I get that error.

Comment: I'm not sure. My docker is at /usr/bin/docker. Maybe you need to reinstall compose as well. Anyway, this is a different problem.

Comment: Reinstalling Docker worked for me, although your instructions did not (for me). Try the ones at https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/ - `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Answer (score 4):

I tried a lot of solution but when I used `sudo apt-get upgrade docker-engine` I see message that I have installed docker with different name as    `docker-ce`   . After I fixed with `sudo apt-get upgrade docker-ce`.

Answer (score 3):

you can downgrade your docker-compose version,if you have installled your docker-compose by:

`pip install docker-compose`

you can uninstall it first by:

`pip uninstall docker-compose`

then,you can run:

`pip install docker-compose==1.3.0`

if you docker-compose up,still show the similar info,you can uninstall it(by `pip uninstall docker-compose`),and install a lower version docker-compose,such as:

`pip install docker-compose==1.2.0`

you can go on the loop, if still show the wrong info.

ps:the detail version number can be found in https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Comment: @hba's answer can only solve the problem shortly,if you reboot,it appears again

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the docker service after upgrading Docker (`sudo service docker restart`).

I had a very similar issue, upgraded Docker, and kept running into the same error message until I restarted the service. (See https://serverfault.com/a/700707/295500.)

Answer (score 2):

Since docker-compose 1.4 you can set the client API version, you don't have to downgrade the client or upgrade the server.

You do not have to set a specific API version either, you can set the environment variable `COMPOSE_API_VERSION=auto` to have it auto-detect the client version.

Answer (score 2):

I found uninstalling the version installed with apt-get and downloading directly from latest version on their download page via command line wget seemed to work..

Comment: I also had problems with the old version of docker provided in ubuntu/trusty repo. To install the newest for trusty see https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ . For newer OS' follow https://docs.docker.com/install/.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Mac - some months ago I installed docker, boot2docker und docker-compose (formerly fig) via [brew](http://brew.sh/). After I played a while with docker, I left it for some reason as it was. Now new [docker-toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) and [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/) come into play and I "just" wanted to use a preconfigured docker-file and say "up". I got the error above.

I tried all things i found on the net - also the downgrade-option (which didn't feel right for me). The thing finally worked, was just to install new [docker-toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) via [homebrew cask](http://caskroom.io/) and upgrade my docker-vm with the following commands:

`docker-machine upgrade docker-dev`

Where "docker-dev" is your docker-vm-Name in Virtualbox (start it, to see the correct name).

Now docker runs fine again and the `docker version` command brings a normal-setup`s output.