# issues with docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Whenever I am trying to run `docker-compose up` it shows the below error related to a version mismatch of client and server.

```
client and server don't have same version (client : 1.19, server: 1.18)
```

Below are the installed versions of docker-compose and docker itself. Neither docker, nor docker-compose have 1.19 and 1.18 versions. So actually this message is referring to which client and server?

```
[root@node1 composetest]# docker -v
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2/1.6.2
[root@node1 composetest]# docker-compose up
client and server don't have same version (client : 1.19, server: 1.18)
```

Further how to fix this issue. I am using centos 6 and  have upgraded the docker to latest version.I had installed docker-compose using pip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [docker-compose up leads to "client and server don't have same version (client : 1.14, server: 1.12)" error but client and server have the same version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727171/docker-compose-up-leads-to-client-and-server-dont-have-same-version-client)

Answer (score 7):

As of docker-compose 1.4 you can now set the client API version, so you don't have to downgrade the client, or upgrade the server.

Set the environment variable `COMPOSE_API_VERSION=auto` to have it auto-detect the client version, or `COMPOSE_API_VERSION=1.18` to set the exact version.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there's a mismatch in API versions.
Seems like your docker daemon is not updated.

Here's my output for `# docker version`:

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to downgrade your docker client to version `1.6` or upgrade the server to version `1.7` to have an API match.

The versions are the API versions and not the product versions.