# client and server don't have same version (client : 1.21, server: 1.18)

Tags: docker, server, client, docker-compose, dockerfile

my:Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2 
my:docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245 
erreur: ERROR: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.21, server: 1.18)

How i can solve this problem Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker-compose up leads to "client and server don't have same version (client : 1.14, server: 1.12)" error but client and server have the same version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727171/docker-compose-up-leads-to-client-and-server-dont-have-same-version-client)

Answer (score 1):

If your server version (1.6.2) is correct, that's from back in May 2015 and extremely old. It predates `docker network` and `docker volume`, build ARGs, privileged containers, DNS discovery, and many other features you may expect. You should really upgrade this to a current release.

With docker-compose, you can use the `COMPOSE_API_VERSION` variable to tell compose which server API version to use, but as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/), this is not supported and some errors are expected, particularly when you have a significant version mismatch like you do.

Comment: When i try to install docker and docker-compose in my pc (ubuntu 14.04 trusty) i have this problem: Unable to find docker-ce package links: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository how can i resolve this problem? Also,when i install docker compose via pipe and docker via "apt-get install" I have this errer ; server and client haven't same version!!! haw can i find docker and docker-compose which are compatible version?

Comment: Try following the steps at get.docker.com.

Comment: Trusty support is available at an older version: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/