# What is the exact version of docker-compose to use with docker 1.7.0?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos6

I am trying to run docker 1.7.0 in CentOS 6. I tried using docker-compose 1.12.0 but
got this "Error:client and server don't have same version(client API version:122, server API version:1.19). So I am trying to find out which docker-compose version support in my case.

Other info:

OS: Centos 6.10
Kernel:2.6.32
Docker client/server version:1.7.0
Docker client/server API version :1.19

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose up leads to "client and server don't have same version (client : 1.14, server: 1.12)" error but client and server have the same version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727171/docker-compose-up-leads-to-client-and-server-dont-have-same-version-client)

Comment: I have go through that answer but I did not get the exact version of the docker-compose. And I already tried most of the steps suggested in that answer by upgrading and downgrading the version.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer it is docker-compose 1.4.0.